# PostBack of ASPxComboBox not firing in DevExpress when used in a custom PropertyEditor

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, xaf

I am working on a DevExpress XAF application, where I need to define one of the properties of a business object with a custom property editor in order to show it with a dropdown list that gets populated from another Business Object like below:

```
[ImmediatePostData(true)]
[ModelDefault("PropertyEditorType", "CollateralSaleTypePropertyEditor")]
[Size(140)]
public string COLLATERAL_SALE_TYPE
{
    get { return GetPropertyValue<String>("COLLATERAL_SALE_TYPE"); }
    set
    {
        SetPropertyValue("COLLATERAL_SALE_TYPE", value);
        // OnChanged("COLLATERAL_REPOSSESSION_DATE");
    }
}
```

Furthermore, I have defined the `CollateralSaleTypePropertyEditor` and have set the AutoPostBack to true: `_dropDownControl.AutoPostBack = true;`

The problem I am facing is that this post back does not occur, and the server side event of `SelectedIndexChanged` does not get raised:

```
//Server side event that is not raised
_dropDownControl.SelectedIndexChanged += control_SelectedIndexChanged;
//Client side event that is raised                   
_dropDownControl.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = "function (sender, e) { e.processOnServer=false;}";
```

So basically every time I change the selected item nothing happens. I found the following link which explains the reason on updating [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q523648/immediatepostdata-not-working-in-custom-property-editor). But even after I follow the steps nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution to your problem is obvious. The issue is with this line:

```
dropDownControl.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = 
                  "function (sender, e) { e.processOnServer=false;}";
```

Since you have specified `e.processOnServer=false`, `SelectedIndexChanged` event is generated at the client side but it will not hit the server.

If you want `SelectedIndexChanged` to reach the server side you need either to remove the client side handler completely or change it to have `e.processOnServer=true;`.

Comment: Hey, I solved it and yes the processedOnServer property had to be set to true, this appeared to be an issue of the DropDown control in particular.

Comment: @kejsiStruga glad it helped!. Would appreciate if you accept the answer then.